# Grammar after word 'making'

Tags: tense

> She shifted in her chair, making it **creak**

Why it is wrong to use past tense after making (i.e., making it creaked)?

Because 'shifted' is past tense, I wonder why I can't use past tense after 'making'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you can't use *making it* ***creaked***, is because whenever *make* is followed by another verb, the other verb takes the infinitive form without *to*.

From [the British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/verbs-followed-infinitive):

> Two very common verbs – ***make*** and ***let*** – are followed by the **infinitive without** ***to***. They take the pattern:
>
> - **Verb + noun + infinitive**
>   *My parents **made me come home** early.*
>   *They wouldn't **let me stay out** late.*

The infinitive is the base form of a verb, without any tense of its own:

> She *made* it ***creak***.
>   She *makes* it ***creak***.
>   She *will make* it ***creak***.

In the sentence in the question, although *make* is an auxiliary verb, it's using the present participle—which is, itself, without tense. As such, the tense of the sentence is determined by the initial verb:

> She *shifted* in her chair, *making* it ***creak***.
>   She *shifts* in her chair, *making* it ***creak***.
>   She *will shift* in her chair, *making* it ***creak***.

Answer (score -4):

**Update2: now I know why my answer is not favored**

The OP saying "making it creaked" meant that the "creaked" is the past tense. And that's what he said in the question:

> Because 'shifted' is past tense, I wonder why I can't use **past tense**
>   after 'making'.

But unfortunately, I didn't see that. The moment I saw the phrase "making it creaked", I assumed it must be the past completion.

Because it's a common sense. No matter which word you replace 'make' with.

let sb. do sth.

stop sb. to do sth. / stop sb. doing sth.

suggest sb. to do sth.

etc.

There is never a usage like "suggested sb. to did sth."

That's just way too basic.

"make sb. do sth." is just omitting the word "to", it won't let the "do" become "did" no matter what. (However I don't have any reference to give you right now. I'm only telling you the fact according to my knowledge of English.)

### **Update1: the short answer**

1. why you can't use "making it creaked"

Because 'creak' is an intransitive verb. For example, you can't say "You're looked" or "Look you". You have to say "You're looked at" or "You're seen" or "Look at you".

And another reason is, 'a chair creaks' has a meaning, while 'creak a chair' doesn't mean anything, even if it was grammatically correct.

You just need to look up the word 'creak'.

2. why we can use "making it creak"

You can refer to [make on Oxford Learner Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/make_1). 
Detailed explanation is below.

3. why you can't use "making it to creak"

Same as the last one, just refer to the dictionary. The form "make somehthing to do something" has a different meaning.

Detailed explanation is below.

4. the 'creaked' in "making it creaked" is not past tense. It is past completed.

### **(Above is the short answer)**

---

This is simple.

You can say

> She made the grass cut.
>   (This sentence may be awkward, but it is grammatically correct. 
>   "She had/got the grass cut" would be better.)

Or

> He can't make his English understood.

But you can't say

> She shifted in her chair, making it creaked.

Because a chair can't be creaked. A chair creaks.

And that sentence just means, that the action of shifting the chair made the chair start creaking.

--------------Update--------------

Some comments say I lack some kind of sourcing

> ...you haven't sourced anything you've said - @Bee

So, here is the source you need: [make on Oxford Learner Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/make_1)

It says:

> 6. make somebody/something/yourself + adj. to cause someone or something
>      to be or become something
>
>    - The news made him very happy.
>    - She made her objections clear.
>    - He made it clear that he objected.
>    - The full story was never made public.
>    - Can you make yourself understood in Russian?
>    - She couldn't make herself heard above the noise of the traffic.
>    - The terrorists made it known that tourists would be targeted.
> 7. make somebody/something do something to cause someone or something to
>      do something
>
>    - She always makes me laugh.
>    - This dress makes me look fat.
>    - What makes you say that (= why do you think so)?
>    - Nothing will make me change my mind.

So **make something do something** is absolutely correct.

Then why can't a chair be creaked? Because 'creak' is an intransitive verb. 
You cannot say a chair is creaked. That just doesn't make sense!

> Your logic doesn't hold. Consider this sentence: She shifted in her chair, so it creaked. That's completely grammatical. - @J.R.♦

The word 'creaked' in your sentence is in its past tense. What I said was 'A chair can't **be** creaked'. And that's apparently Past completion(pluperfect).

And you're not anwsering the OP's question as well. The OP is asking above how to use the word 'make', but where is the word 'make' in your sentence?

Are you opposing my point just for fun?

> I don't think your reasoning is correct - a chair "creaks," but a
>   chair can be "made to creak" (the verb is actually in the infinitive
>   in this construction). We also need to deal with the reason why
>   "making" is not in the past tense.... - @TypeIA

Yes, a chair can be "made to creak". But I saw the OP's question as

> Why "making it creak" instead of "making it creaked"?

So I pressumed that the OP already knew "making it to creak" is invalid.

Maybe that's my fault. So I'll show that.

Still from the link [make on Oxford Learner Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/make_1):
The only explanation of the form "**make something to do something**" is quoted as below:

> 2. make something to write, create, or prepare something
>
>    - These regulations were made to protect children.
>    - My lawyer has been urging me to make a will.
>    - She has made (= directed or acted in) several movies.

Using this form, the word 'make' means create. 
More specifically, If you say 'make the chair to do something', it means the chair is created in order to do that thing.

Apparently this is not the case.

> We also need to deal with the reason why "making" is not in the past
>   tense.... - @TypeIA

No we don't. The OP is not asking this. He's asking the gramma **after** the word 'make'. Please read the question. (I have made this as a comment below, but it seems to be deleted)

Comment: I don't think your reasoning is correct - a chair "creaks," but a chair can be "made **to creak**" (the verb is actually in the infinitive in this construction). We also need to deal with the reason why "making" is not in the past tense. And although "she made the grass cut" is _technically_ grammatical, it is _very_ awkward. No native speaker would say or write this.

Comment: @SP999 you still shouldn't be using sentences in your answer which are awkward, plus you haven't sourced anything you've said. Have a look at the [Help Pages](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Your logic doesn't hold. Consider this sentence: _She shifted in her chair, so it creaked._ That's completely grammatical.

Comment: @SP999 "For example, you can't say 'You're looked'." No, but you can say *you looked*. Your reasoning (conflating intransitivity with verb tense) is faulty.